# Inserting data - Mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

How do you insert columns from two separate tables simultaneously into a third table in mysql? If i use two insert into queries, the data from the second query is put beneath the data from the first query, but i want them to appear on the same rows not one beneath the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql's [insert ... select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) command and join the 2 source tables together in the select part of the query:

```
insert into target (col1, col2)
select source1.col1, source2.col2
from source1
inner join source2 on source1.id=source2.s1_id
```

This way data from the 2 source tables will appear in the same record within the target table.